# Push single file in directory to github new repository?

Tags: git, github

I currently have a file in a repo and have created a new repo, but cannot get the file on the new repo without pushing the entire contents of the directory along with it. I would like to push just the single file from the directory not all of the other contents. I have been doing

```
git add mygame.rb
git commit -m 'game scores'
git add remote new_origin github.com/etc...
git push new_origin master
```

After this is done all the from the directory files are uploaded to my new repo even though I never 'added' them with the git add command. All these files are already in my old repo, just basically want to move 1 file to the new repo. 
git status just returns "# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)"

Comment: `git ls-files` if its listing all your files, probably you have added all your files accidentally to index. If so use `git reset <file_name>` to have those file untracked and removed from index. You can then push the one file alone.

Comment: after using git reset command, then using git ls-files it still lists all the files in the directory.

Comment: So you have two repositories, one with several old files, and you would like to create a new repo with only `mygame.rb`?

Comment: @Ordep81: Mistake from me. :) `git rm --cached file_name`. not git rest

Comment: Did you mean `git remote add` instead of `git add remote`?

Comment: @henrikhodne, that is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your local repo must not be new and therefore when you add a new remote with `git remote add...` there are other files and history that will get pushed with `git push...`.  This is actually a real cool feature of git.

If you want to start a new remote repository with it's own history and only `mygame.rb` as a file, you could easily:

```
mkdir <full_directory_path>
cp mygame.rb <full_directory_path>
cd <full_directory_path>
git init
git add mygame.rb
git commit -m 'game scores'
git remote add origin github.com/etc...
git push origin master:master
```

Comment: So this worked, but totally didnt understand why. So files in the same directory cant be in different repos?

Comment: Yes files in one directory can be on several remote repos.  This is why I said this is a real cool feature of git.  The new remote repository will get all the history all the files of the original.  It is real easy to get mirrors going with git.  Where I work, we have one remote repository that we consider a sandbox, where no official releases come out of, we can rewrite history before pushing the the more official remote repository where users have certain permissions and curators can sign off.  Our local directories represent both repositories.